# How can I configure separate east/west writers for Aurora in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I have a multi-region system deployed in AWS east and west regions.  For resiliency, I want to have data collected in east write to an east-resident Aurora (Postgresql) db, and west-collected data write to a west-resident Aurora, and then have Aurora do the replication magic to keep the 2 dbs in sync so itbdoesn’t matter which I read from.

This way if east becomes unavailable, west keeps goin with no “failover” action needed on my part, and when east comes back the db replication will eventually level things out.

How can I configure this?

Comment: Have you looked into Aurora GlobalDB? https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/global-database/

Answer (score 0):

With Aurora, you can set up clusters with identical data across AWS regions using Aurora global database:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-global-database.html

In the typical case, the application in every AWS Region funnels all inserts and updates to the cluster in the primary Region, then the changes get propagated to all the secondary Regions. If you want the application in each Region to act like it's writing to its own local cluster, you can set up write forwarding:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-global-database-write-forwarding.html

That way, the writes get sent automatically back to the primary cluster and then propagated back to the secondary ones.